# Rails Average - Discount 0 values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I create arrays which I need to find the averages of as follows:

```
total_rating = []
#add numbers to total_rating
average = total_rating.inject(:+).to_f / total_rating.size
```

How can I remove values of 0 from this average calculation? I dont want the 0 row to be computed in the average calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total_rating.reject(&:zero?)
```